# How to include all header files with one include in c++ project?

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-libraries

I have a folder containing header (.h) and c++ (.cpp) files.

```
Folder/ --- file1.h
        --- file1.cpp 
        --- file2.h
        --- ...
```

I have a main.cpp file located in the same directory as the `Folder` or project (to become library).

```
// main.cpp
#include "./Folder/pointtoallheaders.h"
```

How can I include **one** header file that then includes **all** of the header files associated with the project?

Comment: You could write a header that has an `#include` for every other header. But beware of the impact that including all your headers has, specially on compilation time. If you change *any* header you will have to recompile everything.

Comment: So it has an impact on compilation time, but will it impact run time?

Comment: I don't see how

Comment: Re: "will it impact run time" -- probably not, but it depends on what's in the headers.

Comment: It *could* impact run time, depending on what your headers contain.

Comment: By saying it _could_, are y'all saying if my own functions could be slow therefore slow when called **or** could it be possible that uncalled functions related to header files could slow a program in runtime when not called?

Comment: You could declare a variable in the header, and then make the initialization of that variable execute code.  For instance, a loop that takes a long time to run.

Comment: For a real example, `#include <iostream>` will have *some* impact on execution time, because it has to initialize `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr` and other global objects.

Comment: Thank you @SidS Yksisarvinen PeteBecker and FancoisAndrieux. This is a great place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing somenthing it's quite trivial

You can have a header file in the same folder of the main.cpp that includes all the others:

For instance `allheaders.h`

```
#include "Folder/header1.h"
#include "Folder/header2.h"
#include "Folder/header3.h"
#include "Folder/header4.h"
```

Then in your main function just include `allheaders.h`

```
#include "allheaders.h"

int main(){

}
```

Comment: @GeneralCode, when one is learning all questions are valid, you managed to throw off many good programmers (comment section), I would call that a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Create one header file that will import all header files in your project and then import this specific file from the cpp file

Answer (score 0):

Using cmd in windows you can create single header file. this new header file  should include all your old header file. Just add the new allheader.h into the main program.

FOR %i IN (*.h) DO echo #include "%i">>allheader.h

if you have folder path to add, then the above code can modify with folder name

FOR %i IN (*.h) DO echo #include "FolderName/%i">>allheader.h

Further you can create a bat file for the same process just copy and paste the above command into text file and rename with .bat extension.